# Json parser in android

Tags: android, json

I have below string. i want to get jsonarray from this string keyword like id, title and so on.

```
Json_obj = new JSONObject(result);

                    vid = Json_obj.getJSONArray("id");
                     //vcatid= Json_obj.getJSONArray("title");
                    vtitle= Json_obj.getJSONArray("title");
                     vdesc= Json_obj.getJSONArray("content");
                     //vimgurl= Json_obj.getJSONArray("vimgurl");
                     vidlike= Json_obj.getJSONArray("likes");
                     vidview= Json_obj.getJSONArray("views");
                     //vidfblike= Json_obj.getJSONArray("vidfblike");
                     //vidtwlike= Json_obj.getJSONArray("vidtwlike");
                     storagepath= Json_obj.getJSONArray("url");
                    Log.i("json_Video_id vid.length() ",
                            "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% "
                                    + vid.length());


[{"id":"39","title":"\u0627\u0644\u0631\u0651\u0628\u0627 ","content":"\r\n\u0627\u0639\u0644\u0627\u0646 \u0641\u064a \u0627\u0644\u062a\u062d\u0630\u064a\u0631 \u0645\u0646 \u0645\u0634\u0643\u0644\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0644\u0631\u0628\u0627 \u0639\u0644\u0649 \u0627\u0644\u0639\u0627\u0644\u0645 \u0623\u062c\u0645\u0639.\r\n\u0641\u064a\u062f\u064a\u0648 \u0643\u0644\u064a\u0628 \u0628\u062f\u0642\u0629 \u0639\u0627\u0644\u064a\u0629 HD\r\n\u0645\u0646\u062a\u062c \u0645\u0646\u0641\u0630 \u0648\u0644\u064a\u062f \u0627\u0644\u0633\u0646\u062f New View","url":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/L9aPhl6eST0","views":"264","likes":"6"},{"id":"44","title":"\u062e\u064a\u0648\u0637 \u0627\u0644\u0646\u0648\u0631 \u0645\u062d\u0645\u062f \u0627\u0644\u0639\u0632\u0627\u0648\u064a ","content":"\u0641\u064a\u062f\u064a\u0648 \u0643\u0644\u064a\u0628 \u0644\u0635\u0627\u0644\u062d \u0645\u0634\u0631\u0648\u0639 \u0627\u0644\u0639\u0634\u0631 \u0627\u0644\u0623\u062e\u064a\u0631\r\n\u0643\u0644\u0645\u0627\u062a \u0633\u0644\u0637\u0627\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0633\u0628\u0647\u0627\u0646\r\n\u0623\u062f\u0627\u0621 \u0648\u0644\u062d\u0646 \u0645\u062d\u0645\u062f \u0627\u0644\u0639\u0632\u0627\u0648\u064a\r\n\u0627\u062e\u0631\u0627\u062c \u0645\u062d\u0645\u062f \u062e\u0627\u0637\u0631\r\n","url":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/sOoP6SW-wuo","views":"1156","likes":"10"},{"id":"47","title":"\u062a\u0643\u0627\u0641\u0644 \u0646\u0627\u0635\u0631 \u0627\u0644\u0633\u0639\u064a\u062f ","content":"\r\n\u0644\u0644\u0641\u0642\u062f\u0650 \u0623\u0648\u062c\u0627\u0639\u064c \u062a\u062e\u062a\u0628\u0626 \u0628\u064a\u0646 \u062c\u062f\u0631\u0627\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0623\u0644\u0645 \u0648 \u0623\u0633\u062a\u0627\u0631\u0650 \u0627\u0644\u0635\u0645\u062a .. \u0648 \u062f\u0645\u0648\u0639 \u062a\u0628\u0644\u0650\u0651\u0644\u064f \u0635\u062f\u0631\u0627\u064b \u064a\u0636\u062c\u064f\u0651 \u0628\u0627\u0644\u062d\u0646\u064a\u0646 ..\r\n\r\n\u0647\u064a \u0631\u062d\u0644\u0629\u064c \u062a\u0644\u062d\u0641\u062a\u0652 \u0628\u0623\u062d\u0632\u0627\u0646\u0650 \u0627\u0644\u063a\u0631\u0648\u0628 ..\r\n\u0648 \u062d\u0643\u0627\u064a\u0629\u064c \u0643\u064f\u062a\u0628\u062a\u0652 \u0639\u0644\u0649 \u062c\u062f\u0627\u0631\u0650 \u0627\u0644\u0642\u064e\u062f\u064e\u0631 .. \u0623\u0628\u0637\u0627\u0644\u0647\u0627 \u0623\u064a\u062a\u0627\u0645 .. \u0642\u062f \u063a\u0641\u0644 \u0639\u0646\u0647\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0643\u062b\u064a\u064a\u064a\u064a\u0631 \u0645\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0623\u0646\u0627\u0645 !\r\n\r\n\u0642\u062f \u0631\u0633\u0645\u0648\u0627 \u0623\u062d\u0644\u0627\u0645\u064e \u0627\u0644\u0643\u0628\u0627\u0631\u0650 \u0628\u0623\u064a\u062f\u064a\u0647\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u062a\u0639\u0628\u0629 .. \u0641\u0627\u0628\u062a\u0633\u0645\u0648\u0627 \u0628\u0634\u0641\u0627\u0647\u064d \u0634\u0627\u062d\u0628\u0629 ..\r\n\u062a\u063a\u0634\u0627\u0647\u0645 \u0645\u0633\u0627\u0621\u0627\u062a\u064c \u062a\u0628\u0643\u064a \u0627\u0646\u0643\u0633\u0627\u0631 \u0627\u0644\u062d\u064a\u0627\u0629 ..\r\n\u0648 \u064a\u0636\u0645\u0647\u0645 \u0628\u064a\u062a\u064c \u0634\u0647\u0650\u062f\u064e \u062a\u0641\u0627\u0635\u064a\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0623\u0633\u0627\u0629 ..\r\n\u0648 \u062d\u0641\u0650\u0638\u064e \u0623\u0633\u0631\u0627\u0631 \u0627\u0644\u0643\u0631\u0627\u0645\u0629 !\r\n\r\n\r\n\u0641\u064a\u062f\u064a\u0648 \u0643\u0644\u064a\u0628 \u0633\u064a\u0646\u0645\u0627\u0626\u064a \u0645\u0646 \u0625\u0646\u062a\u0627\u062c \u0648\u0625\u0634\u0631\u0627\u0641 \u062c\u0645\u0639\u064a\u0629 \u062a\u0643\u0627\u0641\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u062e\u064a\u0631\u064a\u0629 \u0628\u0627\u0644\u0645\u062f\u064a\u0646\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0646\u0648\u0631\u0629 takaful.sa","url":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/YyYmy79pKfs","views":"181736","likes":"1141"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you parse JSON Array

```
JsonElement json = new JsonParser().parse(response);
JsonArray array = json.getAsJsonArray();
Iterator iterator = array.iterator();
List<CustomClass> obj_list = new ArrayList<CustomClass>();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        JsonElement json2 = (JsonElement) iterator.next();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        CustomClass obj = gson.fromJson(json2, CustomClass.class);
        obj_list.add(obj);
    }
```

Here, `CustomClass` will be a class with the properties you want. That means the properties you get in Array, e.g. id, title, content, likes, views, url.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The outmost container of your JSON data is an array and not an object (it start and ends with square brackets). Thus, you need to use the class JSONArray and then iterate over all elements of the array:

```
String jsonString = ...
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(jsonString);

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);
    String id = obj.getString("id");
    String title = obj.getString("title");
    ...
}
```